# Creating Mockito test case for Spring Boot module

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5, spring-test

I have a spring boot module :

```
Mainproject
-web
-model
-repository
-service
```

I have created mockito test cases for web .
How should i create mockito test cases for service layer .

I am not able to use any of the autowire as i dont have the Application context . it gives me error:

```
package service;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ProvidrsServiceTest {
    
    @Autowire
    config config;

}
```

Secondly i have this bean of config:

```
class config{

@value
@value
@value..

}
```

it is just having some values from property file . can i mock this ? how . please tell .

Can you tell me how should i structure the mockito test classes . should i place all the test classes in web layer as there i am able to get the context .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service layer should be independent from your framework. So you might want to refactor your code to remove all framework dependencies from your service.

Once this is done you can use the `org.mockito.Mock` annotation on your calling services / repositories to create a mock of them.

If your config is already independent from the framework then you can also mock it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Integration test using `@SpringBootTest` but that is not recommended for unit testing as the spring takes sometime to load the application context and it can delay your entire test suite. I found [this tutorial](https://reflectoring.io/unit-testing-spring-boot/) helpful which may help you to identify how to write tests for different modules of spring. Please let me know if this helps!